# Is it possible to use already build Azure resources in Teams toolkit

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, teams-toolkit

I'm creating Teams app, but I have already created bot application and resources needed, thus I don`t need form Teams toolkit to create additional ones. Is it possible to use already build ones and where should I state them in Toolkit files(manifests/parameter files)?

According to MS documentation upon Provisioning and based what is selected to be used in Teams app - Provisioning command triggers to create the resources(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/provision), and to repeat my question, is it possible to use already build resources and not to create new ones?

Any suggestions/ideas/experiences?

By exploring config file I have found in https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/blob/main/docs/fx-core/teamsfx-env-config.md that if I provide the resources they will not be previsioned and created in azure and I have set them: [image: config.dev.json], but still on Output Provision in the cloud I get: [image: Provision in the cloud results]

Comment: We are checking it from our end and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question, if you have already your own Azure Bot service and hosted bot application code. The only thing you need to do to connect your bot with Teams is to update the bot definition part in [Teams manifest file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#bots).